# No way to boot from network on old IBM 9111-285?

Tags: linux, powerpc

I have an old IBM 9111-285 with AIX 7.1
Consider that Aix 7.2 don't boot on oldest ppc cpu's (this is a power5!)
and Aix 7.1 is near EOL as I know I want to install Linux on it.
Actually I have those "solutions"

```
Linux Debian 11: WORKS ONLY ON PPC64LE, this is BE
Adelie Linux: DON'T BOOT
Linux Debian 12 (is a port for ppc64): boot but..kernel panic.
Centos 6 ppc64: is EOL
Centos 7 ppc64: kernel panic
Gentoo ppc64: Boot and hang after 1 minute with no error, probably a panic.
```

The distribution Opensuse Tumbleweed has dvd iso images for ppc64 and ppc64le
I boot the cd and..kernel panic because cannot mount root image, I think is probably
because my workstation has IDE DVD and a lot of Linux distro now don't support old ide
with default kernel So I try the network boot, I have setup a dhcp/tftp/bootp server,
qemu-system-ppc64 can boot (go to openfirmware prompt and after type boot net I get the grub menu and installation start).
With my Ibm workstation I go to openfirmware prompt and...

```
0 > boot net 
BOOTP: chosen-network-type = ethernet,auto,rj45,auto
BOOTP: server   IP =        0.0.0.0
BOOTP: requested filename = 
BOOTP: client   IP =        0.0.0.0
BOOTP: client   HW addr =   *********
BOOTP: gateway  IP =        0.0.0.0
BOOTP: device    /pci@800000020000004/pci@2,4/ethernet@1
BOOTP: loc-code  U787F.001.DPM5MVH-P1-T5

BOOTP: wait 60 seconds for Spanning Tree ... 

BOOTP: BOOTP request fail: 0 

BOOTP: BOOTP request fail: 1 

BOOTP: BOOTP request fail: 2 
BOOTP ERROR: BOOTP request failed, QUIT
        !BA010004 !
```

I try to specify all parameters and...

```
0 > boot net:192.168.0.88,core.elf,192.168.0.10,192.168.0.1                                                                                                                                   
BOOTP: chosen-network-type = ethernet,auto,rj45,auto
BOOTP: server   IP =        192.168.0.88
BOOTP: requested filename = core.elf
BOOTP: client   IP =        192.168.0.10
BOOTP: client   HW addr =   ****************
BOOTP: gateway  IP =        192.168.0.1
BOOTP: device    /pci@800000020000004/pci@2,4/ethernet@1
BOOTP: loc-code  U787F.001.DPM5MVH-P1-T5

BOOTP: wait 60 seconds for Spanning Tree ... 

icmp 5 : redirect
icmp 3 : port unreachable
ERROR: icmp 3
BOOTP: BOOTP request fail: 0 

icmp 3 : port unreachable
ERROR: icmp 3
BOOTP: BOOTP request fail: 1 

icmp 3 : port unreachable
ERROR: icmp 3
BOOTP: BOOTP request fail: 2 
BOOTP ERROR: BOOTP request failed, QUIT
        !BA010004 !
```

Any solution?

EDIT1: Ubuntu 16.04 load fine with this option (but don't go over the lang selection)

```
boot: install-powerpc64 console=hvc0 console=tty0 console=tty1 console=ttyS0,9600,8,n,1 console=ttyS1,9600,8,n,1
```

Comment: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:PPC ?

Comment: Thanks I will try gentoo

Comment: I know this sounds unlikely for a machine that was released in 2004, but maybe the retrocomputing crowd has a favourite way of running Linux on slightly older PPC architectures?

Comment: If Aix 7.1 works, then you are cool. It won't cease to work just beacuse end-of-support.

Comment: Without end of support the system become insecure

Comment: You're not seriously proposing to run this in a production environment are you? If not, then "insecure" is relative - with care you can run an older distribution on older hardware regardless of the comparative age

Comment: Installing some almost-working experimental Linux distribution won't make your system secure either.

Comment: At least they provide latest software, with bugs fixed

Comment: "port unreachable" is an ICMP message sent by your bootp server. It means that no service is listening on its port 67 (bootps) or a firewall is denying its access. Start a tcpdump on your server and see what is actually happening.

Comment: I check with nmap and tried with a qemu vm, and bootps works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: booting from network or cd with the latest ppc64 distro (opensuse tumbleweed, Debian sid) is impossible on 9111-285 because go to kernel panic.
Is possible to install with some tricks a Debian sid (13) port for ppc64 with a custom kernel.

This is how I did for install (you need some little skills: how create fs, know how to create a chroot, known qemu..)

[U]I decline any responsibility in case of damage, of course. Proceed at your own risk[/U]

a)Install directly from DVD or Network is useless, go directly to a kernel panic

b)I have installed first the system (on a qemu-ppc-64 Virtual Machine, then I boot it to check if works..)
and works.

c)Now we have to create a custom kernel for the problematic 9111-285 Ibm Workstation
so I boot the vm + a USB empty disk in a X86 pc

```
#!/bin/bash

CDROM=/dev/sr0
DISCO=linux.qcow2
RAM=4096
BOOT=d

qemu-system-ppc64 -m $RAM \
-boot $BOOT \
-drive file=$DISCO,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0 \
-device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi \
-device scsi-hd,drive=drive-virtio-disk0 -drive file=/dev/sdd,if=virtio \
-netdev tap,id=n1,ifname=tap1,script=no,downscript=no -device virtio-net,netdev=n1 -smp 4 -cdrom $CDROM -accel tcg -nographic
```

d)after the system boot, we want to create a new system with a custom kernel on empty disk, so we partition the disk in this way (the system see it as /dev/vda)

```
fdisk -l /dev/vda
Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/vda1  *     2048     16383     14336     7M 41 PPC PReP Boot
/dev/vda2       16384 558817279 558800896 266,5G 8e Linux LVM

sfdisk -d /dev/vda
label: dos
label-id: 0xc9c164f5
device: /dev/vda
unit: sectors
sector-size: 512

/dev/vda1 : start=        2048, size=       14336, type=41, bootable
/dev/vda2 : start=       16384, size=   558800896, type=8e
```

e)we can format the vda2 partition in the way we want, personally I use lvm+ext4 because is safe and tested
there is no need to separate boot partition, we mount the lvm root on /mnt

`pvcreate /dev/vda2 vgcreate myvg /dev/vda2 lvcreate -n root -L 50G myvg lvcreate -n home -L 50G myvg lvcreate -n swap -L 16G myvg mount /dev/myvg/root /mnt mount /dev/myvg/home /mnt/home`

f)we can use debootstrap program but..
it fail

g)so I have follow this strange way I have download all this stuff (ignore missing packages) for ppc64 (site debian-packages)

```
adduser
apt
apt-transport-https
apt-utils
base-files
base-passwd
bash
bash-completion
bsdmainutils
bsdutils
ca-certificates
coreutils
cpio
cron
dash
debconf
debconf-i18n
debian-archive-keyring
debian-ports-archive-keyring
debianutils
diffutils
dmidecode
dmsetup
dpkg
e2fslibs
e2fsprogs
findutils
gcc-6-base
gnupg
gnupg-agent
gpgv
grep
gzip
hostname
ifupdown
init
init-system-helpers
iproute2
iptables
iputils-ping
isc-dhcp-client
isc-dhcp-common
kmod
libacl1
libapparmor1
libapt-inst2.0
libapt-pkg
libapt-pkg6.0
libassuan0
libattr1
libaudit-common
libaudit1
libblkid1
libbsd0
libbz2-1.0
libc-bin
libc6
libcap-ng0
libcap2
libcomerr2
libcrypt1
libcryptsetup4
libcurl3-gnutls
libdb5.3
libdebconfclient0
libdevmapper1.02.1
libdns-export162
libelf1
libestr0
libfastjson4
libfdisk1
libffi6
libgcc-s1
libgcc1
libgcrypt20
libgdbm3
libgmp10
libgnutls30
libgpg-error0
libgssapi-krb5-2
libhogweed4
libhogweed6
libidn11
libidn2-0
libip4tc0
libip6tc0
libiptc0
libisc-export160
libk5crypto3
libkeyutils1
libkmod2
libkrb5-3
libkrb5support0
libksba8
libldap-2.4-2
libldap-common
liblocale-gettext-perl
liblogging-stdlog0
liblognorm5
liblz4-1
liblzma5
libmd0
libmnl0
libmount1
libncurses5
libncursesw5
libnetfilter-conntrack3
libnettle6
libnettle8
libnewt0.52
libnfnetlink0
libnghttp2-14
libnpth0
libp11-kit0
libpam-modules
libpam-modules-bin
libpam-runtime
libpam0g
libpcre2-16-0
libpcre2-8-0
libpcre3
libpipeline1
libpopt0
libprocps6
libpsl5
libreadline7
librtmp1
libsasl2-2
libsasl2-modules-db
libseccomp2
libselinux1
libsemanage-common
libsemanage1
libsepol1
libslang2
libsmartcols1
libsqlite3-0
libss2
libssh2-1
libssl1.0.2
libssl1.1
libstdc++6
libsystemd0
libtasn1-6
libtext-charwidth-perl
libtext-iconv-perl
libtext-wrapi18n-perl
libtinfo5
libtinfo6
libudev1
libunistring0
libunistring5
libustr-1.0-1
libuuid1
libxapian30
libxtables12
libxxhash0
libzstd1
login
logrotate
lsb-base
mawk
mount
multiarch-support
nano
ncurses-base
ncurses-bin
netbase
openssl
passwd
perl-base
pinentry-curses
procps
readline-common
rsyslog
sed
sensible-utils
systemd
systemd-sysv
sysvinit-utils
tar
tasksel
tasksel-data
tzdata
udev
util-linux
vim-common
vim-tiny
wget
whiptail
xxd
zlib1g
zstd
```

and I decompress it in the "newroot" /mnt

how to do? use a script like this

```
vim script.sh

#!/bin/bash

set -x
ar x $1 && tar -xvf data.tar.?z && rm *z
```

and exec it for all .deb files downloaded (I put those in the directory /mnt/paccgh)

`cd /mnt find paccgh/ -type f -name *deb -exec ./script.sh {} \;`

we do chroot /mnt..and works!

```
for i in dev proc sys; do mount -o bind -v /$i/ /mnt/$i;done

chroot /mnt
```

now in the chroot go to the directory where the list of
packages with .deb extension were and reinstall it with dpkg

`cd /paccgh dpkg -i --force-all *deb`

we have now a pseudo-ready system, fix the broken packages
with this command

`apt -f install`

or reinstall again with dpkg this time without force

`dpkg -i *deb`

you are ready when dpkg -l return no packages with incomplete or broken flag

`dpkg -l|grep -v ii`

h)proceed with those steps

° install main packages: apparmor, systemd, login, openssh-server, iputils, cron, at, acl, passwd, fstools (lvm, mdadm, btrfs-progs, ext2utils, etc..)

`apt -y install lvm mdadm ext2utils openssh-server...`

° configure fstab (don't use /dev/vda* or /dev/sda use LABEL or UUID, or on reboot don't boot because the disk which now is vda, on a real machine became sda)

`UUID=1234..... swap             swap        defaults               0   0 UUID=2345..... /                ext4        defaults,acl            1   1 UUID=4585..... /home            ext4        defaults,acl            1   2`

you can obtain uuid using blkid

° configure users and set a password for root

```
adduser youruser
echo -e 'yourpassword\nyourpassword\n'|passwd root
echo -e 'yourpassword\nyourpassword\n'|passwd youruser
```

i)now the most important thing, the custom kernel, personally I follow this way, I have downloaded the latest [lts kernel](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.14.328.tar.xz) from kernel.org (4.14.328 at this time), I decompress it in /usr/src and I create the Debian packages using this way

`apt -y install build-essential linux-source bc kmod cpio flex libncurses5-dev libelf-dev libssl-dev dwarves bison`

`cd /usr/src/linux-4.14.328`

for the .config I copied the old config from Debian 8 ppc64 kernel (the latest system which install on 9111-285 without panic) and I did "make old config", for the new "answers" I have copied from the Gentoo kernel from [here](https://pastebin.com/1da9McMN) and from my Slackware kernel configuration, this is the finally [.config](https://pastebin.com/1X545Lph) ready for use.

After did this do

`nice make -j`nproc `bindeb-pkg`

after 6-9 hours the kernel is ready..but I don't know why it create a powerpc package instead of ppc64, we can install it with force-all

`dpkg -i --force-all /usr/src/linux*deb`

l)now we miss only the grub package

`apt -y install grub-ieee1275`

install it on disk

`grub-install /dev/vda1`

update initramfs

`update-initramfs -cv -k all`

update grub

`update-grub2`

l)we are ready, exit from chroot, umount it and poweroff the vm

`exit umount /mnt/dev/pts umount /mnt/proc umount /mnt/sys shutdown -h now`

m)Now the big problem...our disk is SATA, and the 9111-285 use scsi or ide disks we can solve using a docking station like [this one](https://www.amazon.it/Docking-Station-Multifunzionale-Supporta-WLX-875/dp/B00AFUONCQ) (usb2!) insert the disk and boot the workstation to SMS menu (you need a serial connection), boot from livecd (Debian 8)
and copy with dd the content of SATA disk to SCSI disk, when you boot leave the usb-sata disk
attached, the system boot from scsi disk, but read from usb disk (you can boot direct from scsi but you have to modify grub from grub-console)

n)once arrived to linux login prompt use rsync to copy all data from usb-sata disk to scsi disk

with rsync follow this way

vim file.txt
 `/mnt /proc /sys /dev`

do mount, rsync..

```
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
rsync -avAXHhSP --exclude-from=file.txt / /mnt
for i in dev proc sys;do mount -o bind /$i/ /mnt/$i;done
chroot /mnt
```

recreate initramfs and fix fstab

```
vim /etc/fstab #update uuid's or labels

update-initramfs -cv -k all
```

reinstall grub and reboot finally with scsi disk

```
grub-install /dev/sda1
update-grub2
exit
shutdown -r now
```